# Экстратонкий, экстра-тонкий или экстра тонкий?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Как правильно пишется экстра тонкий?

Answer (score 1):

Экстратонкий.

Правило:

**Экстра... - приставка, пишется слитно, но: экстра-класс, экстра-почта, экстра-тайм, экстра-энд.**

Answer (score 0):

> Как правильно пишется экстра тонкий?

Как единое прилагательное - слитно: ***экстратонкий*** ("крючок вязальный экстратонкий").

Однако при самостоятельном использовании, в значении "объект, товар высшего сорта" "экстра" пишется раздельно. Правда, в этом случае прилагательное обычно предшествует: "лист тонкий экстра". Или же "экстра" используется в качестве *названия* сорта и  тогда требует кавычек: **диск "экстра" тонкий**  (примеры из рекламных объявлений).

Дефисное написание здесь, похоже, всегда будет ошибкой, оно предполагает использование "тонкий" в роли существительного, а такое представить очень трудно.

Answer (score 0):

Экстратонкий - прилагательное, где экстра - приставка латинского происхождения = сверхтонкий. Такие слова относят к сложным, потому что приставка экстра употребляется и как корень неизменяемого слова.

Большой толковый словарь:

> ЭКСТРА, неизм.; в зн. прил. [от лат. extra - сверх меры, чересчур]
>   Самый высший, самый лучший (о сорте товара). Масло экстра. Чай экстра.
>
> ЭКСТРА-; ЭКСТРА... [от лат. extra - вне, снаружи и extra - вне, сверх]
>   Первая часть сложных слов. Обозначает выход за пределы чего-л.;
>   высшего качества. Экстразональный, экстра-класс,
>   экстралингвистический, экстра-матч, экстра-мода,экстрановый,
>   экстра-ревизор.

Дефисное написание - полуслитное, здесь соединяются два значения "экстра" - это неизменяемое слово со значением "высшего качества", должно писаться раздельно, но стоит перед словом, которое определяет, и сливается с ним в одно сложное, а если это одно слово, то написание полуслитное, т.е. через дефис: экстра-класс, экстра-матч, экстра-мода.

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sostav-slova/pristavka/inoyazyichnyie-pristavki-v-russkom-yazyike-i-ih-znachenie.html

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0